# Hair particles don't work properly

Tags: particles

trying to do hair particles but it always starts at the 3D cursor and just goes a random direction
[image: what's happening]

[image: what should be happening]
<-what it should look like

can anyone help?
emitter works fine
[image: Emitter]

Comment: make a copy of the object and with that one apply all modifiers before you add hair, does it work? if it does check order of modifiers, maybe a subdiv is causing havoc

Comment: i have no modifiers active. i just shade smooth

Comment: is it possible you add the blend file so i can have look

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bmh67NW7LRbujjeLnM08DxHG5zF8ScZs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have it set to emitter not hair